# WordPress secondary sidebar works in Safari but doesn’t show in Firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

I’ve been tweaking a WordPress theme with only one sidebar to include a second one. Looks like it worked, I’ve managed to include a second side bar in the home of the theme.

[image: Picture of a website]

This new sidebar occupies 2 columns, but for some reason in Firefox it is not showing up, but it is there in a minimal space. Is like Firefox is assigning a very little height property to it.

Here’s an image:
[image: Picture of a website with developer tools activated]

I’m not quite sure of how does the theme calls the sidebars, so I just placed the second sidebar in the main home page.

Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 main-content">(...)</div>
    <?php Bunyad::core()->theme_sidebar(); ?>  <!--I think this calls the first sidebar-->
    <aside class="col-2 sidebar2"> <!--this is a copy of the code for the first sidebar that can be found in a separate file called sidebar.php -->
        <ul>
            <?php if (!dynamic_sidebar('cs-sidebar_publicidad')) : ?>
            <?php _e("<li>Nothing yet.</li>", 'bunyad'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div> <!-- .row -->
```

And this would be the CSS for the second sidebar:

```
.main .sidebar2 {
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
}

.main .sidebar2:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

If you have any idea of what’s going on with Firefox, or any suggestion to correct the code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you possible add a link to the website or a jsfiddle that reproduces that problem?

Comment: ok, here's the link: http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/

Comment: If you have an adblocker disable that.  I disabled mine and I could see the second sidebar.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you!

Comment: even tough that problem is solved could you help me with the sidebar code? It's so messy, that its giving me some other troubles, for example, i would like to position the bar right next to the Slider.... its weird to call the first sidebar with php and the second with plain html...