# Proper way to call a second sidebar in main page wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, sidebar

I've decided to start a new question. with info from a previouss [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662208/worpress-secondary-sidebar-works-in-safari-but-doesnt-show-in-firefox), because i think i was missing the point.

I'm trying to have 2 sidebars (at the same time) in the main home of a blog i'm designing. For now I have achieved it but in a messy way...

I (think) i registered both sidebars, made html code for both and styled both in the Css.
But my knowledge in php is so little that i couldn't manage to know how the sidebar was being called in the maing page. I know `get_sidebar`should be used but it only appears one time in the code and as a function itself.

```
<?php if ((!in_the_loop() && Bunyad::posts()->meta('layout_style') == 'full') OR Bunyad::core()->get_sidebar() == 'none'): // largest images - no sidebar? ?>
```

(I think this Bunyad plug in is in part responsible... any one had issues with it before?)

So i just pasted the html code for the second sidebar where i wanted it to be.

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 main-content">(...)</div>

<?php Bunyad::core()->theme_sidebar(); ?>  <!--I think this calls the first sidebar-->

<aside class="col-2 sidebar2"> <!--this is a copy of the code for the first sidebar that can be found in a separate file called sidebar.php -->
    <ul>

    <?php if (!dynamic_sidebar('cs-sidebar_publicidad')) : ?>
        <?php _e("<li>Nothing yet.</li>", 'bunyad'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </ul>
</aside>

</div> <!-- .row -->
```

(`cs-sidebar_publicidad`is the ID for the second sidebar, i created it in the WP admin panel...)

Any help is widely appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add a side bar or a block in wp page

- register the new sidebar in functions.php of your theme:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar
  you can use the existing register code from the first sidebar as a guideline;
- create a second sidebar template; possibly make a copy of sidebar.php, rename it to (for example) sidebar-two.php, adapt the 'dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )' (or similar) section, edit the respective css classes and ids;
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes
- edit all respective templates, and add  into the position it needs to be to comply with your html structure;
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar